# Apache Artemis Publisher and Subscriber Authorization

Tags: java, publish-subscribe, activemq-artemis

I am evaluating the [Apache Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) JMS broker from topic security point of view. Normally, any client with the topic address can publish or read the messages to/from the topic.

In my scenario, a message broker should have the ability to revoke any subscriber/publisher at any time. Once a subscriber/publisher access is revoked on the topic by the message broker, the client should not be able to publish or subscribe to the messages on that topic

Please suggests if there is something available out of the box in apache Artemis or a suitable approach to add this authorization layer on top of the broker.

Comment: This question is just too broad. If you asked these questions about each individual broker that would work, but asking them for all brokers at once means that it's going to be very hard to identify a "correct" answer. This isn't how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @JustinBertram We change the question as advised. Thank you!

Comment: The updates look good. I voted to reopen. Hopefully others will agree.